# MS Access 365, Using DLookup to look up info on a non combo box

Tags: ms-access

helping my dad program a temp database in the meantime for our HVAC business (we used to use paradox but that mess has finally stopped working).

What he is looking for is the ability to type in a phone number and pull up the customer's name (First name, Last name) and Cust ID (Our identifying value for the customers). We have a lot of phone numbers so a combo box displaying them all would not be ideal. Any ideas?

What I have currently is 5 boxes that have

```
=DLookup("CustID","CustT","Phone=" & PhoneLookupF)
```

But they don't seem to update when I change the value on the PhoneLookupF box by typing stuff in.

Comment: Why do you show 3 field names separated with `/`? Why does expression have `//The table`? What do you mean by a 'lot'. I have comboboxes with a 'lot' of values and they work fine.

Comment: Hey sorry bout that i should've formated it better.

=DLookup("custid","CustT" ,"Phone=" & PhoneLookupF)
Was trying to comment on the code to give better insight. and it would be around 10,000-20,000 entries. Been in business for a while

Answer (score 1):

If object (field, table, query, form, report) names have spaces, then enclose in `[ ]`. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. If Phone is a text field, need apostrophe delimiters, if not text then remove apostrophes from example.

`=DLookup("[First name]", "CustT", "Phone='" & [PhoneLookupF] & "'")`

`=DLookup("[Last name]", "CustT", "Phone='" & [PhoneLookupF] & "'")`

`=DLookup("[Cust ID]", "CustT", "Phone='" & [PhoneLookupF] & "'")`

This will not recalc until PhoneLookupF loses focus and therefore commits the entered value.

Might find the following tutorials interesting:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html
http://allenbrowne.com/AppFindAsUType.html

Comment: Hey mate thanks for the help. All naming conventions are non spaced with no special characters. Learned that from my C# coding days. Thanks for the tutorials. Ill look into them and see what I can do.